# Proposed close reason: lack of formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, code-formatting

All the numerous questions that dump an unindented, unreadable mess of code onto the site are getting tiresome. I find such posts plain rude, as they suggest:

- "I care nothing about the quality of my question."
- "I care nothing about the quality of Stack Overflow."
- "I care nothing about how much time you have to spend at answering my question."
- "I don't take any pride in what I do/lack professional work ethic."
- Or possibly "I can't be bothered to even spend the minimal effort it takes to find out how to format code on Stack Overflow".

---

There are currently two available options for dealing with such questions:

- Down vote and leave a comment. This rarely ever leads to the original poster learning from their mistake, let alone actually editing their question to make the code readable. Maybe one out of a hundred does. So this does not improve the quality of the site.
- "Spoon-feed" the poster and fix the indention for them. In which case they will certainly learn nothing. They will come back the next day to dump another mess on the site.

You cannot close vote as "unclear what you are asking", because the messy code is accompanied with a textual question. "Unclear what you are asking" suggests that there are problems in that textual part of the question.

We used to have a close reason "must demonstrate minimum effort" which covered poor formatting, but that one was removed. I strongly disagreed with its removal, but we already had that debate over and over in multiple other threads.

If we cannot have that close reason, at the very least let us close questions where the code lacks proper indention. It is a black & white case: either the code has acceptable indention or it does not.

**Therefore I propose a new close reason: lack of formatting.**

I think this would improve the quality of questions considerably. With such a close reason, the poster will be forced to sort out the formatting by themselves and maybe even learn something from it.

Comment: And so the question is doomed: down-vote 10 seconds after posting, thanks for actually reading the proposal. And now for something completely different: the meta bandwagon.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because people do not agree with your proposal. Nothing personal in that.

Comment: Open to abuse. How little formatting is too little, or conversely, how much formatting is enough formatting? What if English is someone's second, third, or even fourth language, and formatting is difficult, but they otherwise ask good questions? Or what about people like [Spektre](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307557/5240004) who make valuable contributions, even though they have an eccentric style? The tools are available to fix the problem posts or close them if they _are_ unclear, duplicated, etc.

Comment: @theB Anyone with minimum knowledge of the given programming language knows how to tell the difference between indented code and not indented code. Of course it shouldn't be just to judge style. As for abuse, please have in mind that the existing tools already allow plenty of it. It is quite common that people decide to edit posts because they don't like the coding style. Which is not ok, yet that isn't a big problem for the site. This close reason would be far less radical than full edits, so I think the potential for abuse is very low.

Comment: In my experience, *almost* all such questions also count as not providing a short but complete example - they typically include far too much code or far too little... so I usually vote to close on those grounds.

Comment: @theB Other close reasons already existing are just as likely to be abused as a "lacks formatting" close reason would be. The "unclear" close reason in particular has a very subjective line between what is acceptable and what isn't.

Comment: I can't think of any examples of poorly formatted questions that don't qualify as unclear what is being asked. If you are able to discern a clear, answerable, on-topic question, then perhaps you're not looking at an incoherent mess after all.

Comment: A correction: Open to abuse was a bit of an overstatement that assumes bad faith on the part of the people using it as a close reason.  I shouldn't have done that, and I'd like to apologize to Lundin for the implication. The  point I was trying to make was that truly unclear questions already have several options available. (As usual @JonSkeet said it more eloquently than I could manage.)

Comment: @Louis - Arguably all close reasons have some subjectivity to them, which is why it takes multiple votes. But, with the other reasons there's some additional information about how the OP should go about fixing their question.  If a question gets closed for "Bad Formatting" then the user fixes it, the question gets re-opened, and then immediately closed as unclear, I'd say that we're ultimately doing new users a disservice.

Comment: If the *only* issue with the question is that someone neglected to Ctrl/Cmd+K their code snippets, then closing and assuming bad faith seems to me a little excessive - and no less rude than the bad faith that you assume. If someone is *habitually* neglecting to format their questions properly, *then* we'll talk.

Answer (score 15):

When someone posts a question whose formatting is FUBAR, you have to spend an incredible amount of effort to be able to read and understand it.

Hence: downvote ("this question is unclear") and vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 12):

### This is why there's an "edit" button

We're a community wiki style site, we're here to find interesting questions and good answers, not to decide if people are rude or not.

If it's messy, tidy it up (or ignore it). If it's a bad question, close it.

I agree that poor formatting can show a lack of thought, which may go hand in hand with a poor quality question... but then we should be closing the question for being poor quality.

**If the question is good but badly formatted, improve it** (or leave others to)

Comment: Sorry but this is not a wiki style site, it is a question & answer site. The goal is to aid with programming problems, not to make Wikipedia 2. There are, for very good reasons, no close reasons such as "question is boring", "I don't like the question", "my personal, subjective belief is that the question is poor" and so on. You cannot close questions for these reasons: a "low quality" question is one which is complete crap with no hope to be salvaged. And what makes you think it is not for us to decide if people are rude? That's a ridiculous statement, we shouldn't tolerate rudeness on SO.

Comment: *That's a ridiculous statement, we shouldn't tolerate rudeness on SO.* Ridiculous? That's pretty rude.

Comment: 'Wiki' in the sense that 'anyone can edit and improve' - not 'Wikipedia'... They are very different things. And again there's a difference between being rude (eg personal attacks), and being inconsiderate in your formatting. By your own definition a question with poor formatting is not 'complete crap **with no hope to be salvaged**' - it can usually be salvaged with 2 minutes of editing.

Comment: @JonStory That's what the proposal is all about: there is currently no way to close such questions and force the poster to edit them, not some innocent bystander. The core issue here is that the lack of quality on SO is becoming a huge problem, the site is rapidly decaying and is in a very poor state currently, compared to where it used to be. Editing code formatting is time consuming: there is not enough people who can and will edit posts manually, in order to counter the massive, continuous flood of crap constantly bombarding the site.

Comment: And that's my point - SO is not about "I'm closing your question until you fix the formatting". We only close questions if we can't understand the question, or it's off topic - not because it's a bit untidy. And there seem to me to be quite a lot of people who are happy to clean up code? Perhaps if you feel there are a lot of posts lying around, the answer is to setup some kind of drive to fix them. I'd quite happily spend an hour fixing up a few dozen.

Comment: @JonStory Perhaps when you have some more experience of editing and reviewing, you'll be of a different opinion. I've spent countless hours on such tasks, yet I see that the overall quality of the site is only decaying. It is a lost battle: manual reviews or edits is not the solution, the site has become too big and burdensome. There are far more users who don't care, than there are users who care. Sooner or later someone will make a competing site but with more emphasis on quality. Then it will quickly kill SO when all expertise move there, just like SO killed Experts Exchange.

Comment: I've got a reasonable amount of experience reviewing and editing (SO itself isn't my most active SE account). You seem to be expressing dissatisfied with the whole site rather than proposing a true solution to the need for better editing (perhaps the real answer is for the site to add a "This looks like code, would you like us to automatically prettify int?" feature). With respect, the downvotes on your question suggest that the community doesn't agree with closing badly formatted questions.

Comment: *"Sooner or later someone will make a competing site but with more emphasis on quality"* I dunno... our emphasis on quality is already pretty damn high, it's just a problem of scale at this point.

Comment: I just want to say that we don't close questions for poor quality, that isn't a close reason. We close questions if they are off-topic based on a set of criteria, none of which pertain to the quality of the question. You can have a very high quality off-topic question and a very low quality on-topic question. We close off-topic questions, we flag very low quality (emphasis on very) questions for moderator attention. Poor quality on-topic questions just get downvoted.