# Is there anything to do but cry when the OP accepts a duff edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I rejected the edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16379360.  The OP of the question accepted it.  The modified `#include < iostream >` notation doesn't work (or doesn't work reliably) and should have been rejected.  I guess I'll go fix it, but is there anything we can do about such mistakes?

I suspect the answer's "No", but I can grumble here.

Comment: How does "rolling the edit back" sound?  The OP has power to accept edits unconditionally, but that shouldn't preclude us from fixing bad ones.

Comment: The OP probably didn't even realize the edit broke that part.

Comment: @BSMP sadly, you might well be right.

Comment: @Makoto some of the edit was reasonable. I fixed it up, anyway.

Comment: The world is made of carbon and programmer tears.

Comment: I'd roll back the edit and then edit the post, copy the pre-rolled-back version into the post while fixing the introduced bug, but maybe I'm weird like that. That would be going by the assumption that roll backs have any impact whatsoever on anything apart from the post itself (e.g. they affect edit bans) - I mean, they **should** (and probably more severely than a suggestion rejection), but I'm not sure they do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The original code was a complete trainwreck format-wise, so the first edit actually substantially improved it. It was actually a good edit, apart from the introduced bug.

(It baffles me why people can be bothered to spend time indenting code for random people who can't even manage such a simple thing themselves... but someone did so there you go.)

What you could have done here is to "accept and edit", meaning that all the indention changes would be passed on and you can fix the bug introduced by the edit. This means that the editor will get credit and rep for the edit.

If you think it is bad style to introduce bugs while editing other people's posts, you could also "edit and reject"... This means that the editor gets no credit and the reject will count towards a review ban, if they keep doing a bad job. But then you'll have to re-do all the indention and spell fixes yourself...

The advantages of "accept & edit" and "reject & edit" is that these give you absolute power of the fate of the edit. Consensus is no longer needed, but your edit will become the accepted one - because you already have enough rep to be trusted to edit without going through review. This is also a good way to override blind "accept" clicks by robo-reviewers.

If you simply accept/reject, then there needs to be a consensus where 3 reviewers have the same opinion, but during that time the OP may at any point accept the edit, overriding the edit reviews.

The OP will get notified about the edit in any of the cases.

---

As a side note, upon encountering

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
```

then all manner of warning bells should start ringing, as this is not valid C nor valid C++. The question was tagged C but there is just no way the code will ever compile in C. It would be more correct to re-tag it C++, even though the code is very C-like. But of course `#include <stdio.h>` is also obsolete style in C++ since early 1990s or so...

So better yet, prompt the OP and ask them if they have any clue at all about what they are doing, since they don't use anything from iostream in their code and they mix C and C++.

In retrospect this was such a complete crap question that nobody should have spent any time fixing it to begin with. Upon encountering it in its original form, I would just down-vote, close-vote as unclear and move on.

Comment: Looks to me more like OP has a very unfirm grasp on what is c and what is c++. The code is entirely (from what I can tell) in c, but the `include <iostream>` betrays that OP maybe just doesn't know that C isn't C++ and vice versa.

Comment: People indent code because all it takes is copy/paste into IDE + [some reformat button] + copy/paste into Q, and you get +2 rep. It may be one of the easiest ways to get rep...I've done it a couple of times myself.

Comment: @pycoder Well I once made a proposal that we shouldn't allow unindented posts on SO and that the OP needs to get taught how to indent their own mess. The proposal got down-voted to meta-hell, so my take is that the community truly loves to indent code for others.

Comment: I frequently use both Accept & Edit and Reject & Edit.  In this case, I wanted to get a message to the editor, so I used plain Reject and said what was wrong in that message, rather than Reject & Edit which doesn't allow you to give a specific message to the editor (and I was being mildly lazy; I didn't want to have to fix the train-wreck thoroughly).  The C vs C++ confusion arises primarily on Windows, I find; the MSVS compilers confuse the issue.

Comment: @Magisch Rather, it tells that the OP doesn't know what they are doing and they are most likely compiling C code in a C++ compiler, which can cause all manner of bugs, including some very subtle ones. Quite often this is the actual reason behind the problem... just yesterday there was a question caused by someone trying to compile C code in VS C++ mode, which is doomed to fail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Reject & edit does give them an (automated message) along the lines of "look here and see what you could have done better". Now, the evil way of solving this would be to copy the edit, reject & edit, paste it all there, fix the bugs and maybe the incorrect tagging. Not quite sure if this proper behavior as a reviewer though.

Comment: *Reject & Edit which doesn't allow you to give a specific message to the editor* You could explain why you rejected the edit in your edit summary. "Removed error introduced in suggested edit" or something. (Supposing you felt like fixing things, which you didn't in this case.)

Comment: @BSMP, Yes, you should explain rejection in the edit summary, but are people more likely to look at the edit summary, or the reasons for rejection? Yes, the conscientious editors *will* look there, once they know to do so. Those are also the users which we most want to give such feedback to, as they might actually change their behavior. However, I would expect that for most editors, who actually look for the status of their edit, will be more likely to see the custom reject message. If it is custom, then it, hopefully, will have more attention paid to it than just the stock messages.

Comment: *`(It baffles me why people can be bothered to spend time indenting code for random people who can't even manage such a simple thing themselves... but someone did so there you go.)`* I do it all the time. It makes the post more readable for others. Usually only takes a minute, sometimes only a few seconds.

Comment: @Draco18s That's not the point. The point is that it is rude to dump some unindented mess on others and expect them to read it. Kind of like someone violently coughing their hand in front of you, before offering for a handshake... The normal thing would be to refuse to touch it. The people who don't, but just smile and shake hands, then goes to clean up _their_ hand afterwards baffles me. Yeah so washing your hands only take a minute... that's not the point. Teaching people basic manners by cleaning up their own mess is the point.

Comment: So...In this analogy, what action is "teaching the other person to wash their hand?"

Comment: @Draco18s Refusing to shake their hand or have anything to do with them until they have learnt how to behave. People who can't even understand that source code must be indented to be readable are hopeless cases - they can never work with programming so why waste time and effort on them? And yes that includes beginners who can't figure out how to do source code formatting and post previews on the site. People who can't even figure out how to use a simple web site clearly lack the brains needed to become programmers.

Comment: This seems contradictory to the whole "every edit that improves the post" mantra of the site. And the first post review queue.  And every other meta post I've seen regarding good edits.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes. That we shouldn't indent people's code for them is my personal opinion. As already mentioned, a majority of the community seems to love hand-feeding imbeciles by indenting their code for them. The dominating SO attitude nowadays is that all crap must be preserved, refined and put on a pedestal, where as many people as possible can come and view it.

Comment: In *my* opinion, giving the edit that indents the code and leaving a revision reason of "properly indented the code" *informs the user* that they did something wrong (as they get the notification and can review the edit). Ignoring the question and dooming them to an endless void of silence doesn't tell them what the problem was. It could be that no one has an answer or it could be because their question is poorly worded, but *they have no idea.*

Comment: @Draco18s Which is why we should have a close reason for this very purpose. Fixing the code for them tells them "It's okay to dump your unindented wall of code here, we have thousands of unpaid slaves that will fix it for you. There is no need to improve or strive to write quality questions - any barely coherent crap is fine and encouraged!" Personally, since I find unindented code rude, I always down vote, leave a comment "Please indent your code", then leave the question never to read it again.

Comment: We have a close reason for bad formatting? Let me see here..."duplicate"...no..."unclear"...not necessarily...it could be a perfectly fine question missing a ctrl-K..."opinion based"...no..."general computing", "server or network admin"...no..."recommend a thing" no..."why isn't this working?"...not necessarily..."can no longer be reproduced due to typographical error"...not necessarily.  I give up, I can't find it.

Comment: @Draco18s Read my comment again...

Comment: You're right I misread your comment. That said, I seem to recall meta posts about things like that and it's always "no, that's what edits are for."  Oh look [here it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307732/1663383)

Comment: @Draco18s Yep, the proposal got downvoted to meta hell. QED.