# Edits that split questions into a problem/question part

Tags: discussion, edits

There is a user who is editing questions into a new format; separating them in a "context" or "problem" section, and a "question" section at the end.
The "context"/"problem" part often rewrites the situation in bullet points.

The user is below 2k, so these edits enter the review queue.

A few examples: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10874434, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10880037,  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10874789

I'm not sure what to make of these edits.
On the one hand, I think they are rather intrusive; I'm not sure I'd want my questions reformatted in this way.
On the other hand, it does seem to make these questions more clear.

So the question is, where do we stand on this type of edit? Should we approve or reject such edits?

Comment: Hello S.L Barth , delighted to be involved thank you for the invitation. I think from my point of view my best guidance comes from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839620/executing-same-code-via-exec-sp-versus-exec-sp-code-in-query-window-report-same which received a good response. In addition I like to get involved in improving the community. If the community feels the formatting is out with the guidelines I accept that. Personally I feel my edits provide a clearer presentation of the facts. Interested to know your thoughts. Scott

Comment: @scott_lotus You're welcome! My initial response to these edits was that  they were too intrusive, but on reflection I started thinking that they do improve things. Right now I'm of mixed minds, and I too will look at the responses here.

Comment: Could you include an example? It doesn't have to be a link to an edit, but a before and after would be good. It's hard to give a blanket "yes" or "no", but I think that clarifying what is background noise and what the actual question is should be considered a good edit in most situations, as long as the edit isn't changing the actual question or the background information and just separating it out.

Comment: @TinyGiant As requested - now that the user is involved in the discussion we can safely point to examples.

Comment: Related to whether or not the edits are good: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307481/bulletpoints-everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find example here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34759843/revisions.

Typically the edits start as a single large paragraph from a new user. My formatting specifically helps to breakdown that large block of text into clearly defined section namely ENVIRONMENT or CONTEXT and PROBLEM or QUESTION.  This differs depending on how well the question was asked in the first place.

I see the process as assiting new users and minimising the chance the question is voted down or closed. If a question is voted down or close a new user maybe scared away from stack to the detriment of the community in my opinion.

Comment: My suggestion: make sure if you're going to make an edit like this that changes the structure of the question that you put a short summary of the question right at the start so that the question list pages will display a meaningful summary. *"Environment

I am new to Selenium so I had some concern, please let me know about this"* isn't very meaningful (and really isn't needed at all in the question anyway..)

Comment: @Kevin B, good point. I was not aware of the impact on the question list page.

Comment: Breaking down a wall of text is for sure an improvement. However, turning the complete text in nothing else but captions and bullet points looks like you are overdoing it...

Comment: I've decided to accept this as the answer. I think these edits may indeed have saved wall-of-text questions from being downvoted. We could discuss the finer points of these edits, but on the whole, I think they are an improvement.

Comment: Please consider using a lighter touch. As noted in [ryanyuyu's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314647), adding a lot of structure can be beneficial for _some_ posts, but in many cases results in a post that is more structure than content. Note also that many poor posts are more in need of closing than editing (i.e. if a post really requires a large amount of structure, it may be too broad for SO). Finally, don't forget to pace yourself; a single user making a lot of edits can add too much to the review queues.

Comment: I think breaking them into readable chunks is very good, but the titles are unnecessary and just add extra time to the time it already takes to read the question.

Answer (score 12):

> I think [the edits] are rather intrusive

Then you must reject as "Clearly conflicts with author's intent."  While the edits might make some things more clear or apparent, intrusive edits will often misrepresent what the author is trying to say.  Maybe some things become more apparent, but that might have the unintended effect of diminishing other aspects of the post.  Because of this, any "intrusive" edit to an already understandable question should be reject.

That being said, if the original post is in such bad shape as to be incomprehensible, then almost anything would be an improvement.  I'd approve any honest attempt to clean up a question into something on-topic and understandable.

---

Addressing these specific edits, I find them marginally more readable.  I'm not a huge fan of overusing bullet lists for a mere problem description.  I think it's needless (superfluous) formatting to break each sentence of a problem description into a bullet point.  If the problem itself is more complicated, then I'd say sure.  But a lot of these questions really only needed a line break or something.

I think this structure can be useful for more complex questions than the ones you've included in the question.  But I would actually reject some of them as "No improvement/**superfluous**" because I hate reading random words as code.  I also don't think stuff like "Does anybody have experience like this one  ?" makes a good summary question.

Answer (score 4):

> On the other hand, it does seem to make these questions more clear.

It could, in some cases. I checked out the first example, and found that it was a *complete mess, both before and after*.

There was quite a bit of [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) in the post - things like "I am new to " and "I had some concern" and "please let me know about this" are all supposed to be removed; OP managed to blend all three of those into a single sentence and lead off with it.

There were numerous grammatical errors ("In new environment..."; repeated incorrect choice of their/there) and a huge run-on sentence. Rearranging into the bullet-point structure helped only slightly with this.

Because the overall question is so short, I don't feel that it benefits from a heavyweight restructuring into separate "environment" and "questions" section. While there are technically are multiple sentences here that should end with a question mark, they do coherently ask about one specific thing. Labelling a section as "Questions" falsely gives the impression that it's okay to ask multiple questions in one post.

Worse, simply splitting the prose into parts and aligning them with bullet points *doesn't necessarily make a coherent bulleted list*. In particular, the "or" in "or is their[sic] any other way to do this?" should at least have been dropped for this attempt. On the other hand: while the questions are all questions, the bullet points in the environment section are *not* coherently... "environment", whatever that means. There are two things being said, but they don't relate to each other. They don't make sense as *items of a list*, so they shouldn't be formatted with bullet points.

Aside from the failure of these formatting devices, the editor *actively made the formatting worse* by introducing code formatting for jargon terms. **Please do not use inline code formatting like this**. It is *for code*. In a broad sense, sure, but still - use it for things *that are actually typed as a part of creating an MRE, or that are proposed to be typed as part of the solution process*.

Don't use inline code formatting for the names of languages, tools or libraries, except when showing code to import a library. Don't use it for language concepts ("To solve this problem, start by writing a class that does..."); do use it for language keywords being used *as keywords* in the context of that sentence ("a `class` declaration is not valid in this context because...") and actual code excerpts ("an error was reported on the line `class Example []` because FooLang does not use square brackets to..."). **Especially** don't use inline code formatting for generic programming concepts (like "runtime", as here, or "IDE").

I gave the question a complete re-edit, although I think it **still** lacks clarity (my **best guess** is that OP wanted to do something along the lines of, asking Selenium to click an element in the page based on screen position, and then use some other code to determine which element was clicked and construct an XPath that selects that element). In particular, OP's use of the term "item" didn't make a lot of sense to me (I didn't want to *assume* that it was intended to mean "tag" or "element").

Answer (score 0):

You're contradicting yourself.

> On the other hand, it does seem to make these questions more clear.

Yes, that's the purpose of the edits, to make question/answers clearer and (typo)error-free.

> ...I'm not sure I'd want my questions reformatted in this way.

Why not? You yourself felt that the post quality is improved. So what's the issue in the edit?

As long as the edit does not change the meaning or context of the post, it should be welcome.