# Kind reminder to remove noise

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

When reviewing suggested edits, I noticed that many edits are proposed only to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), which I consider to be trivial.

I think we can pop up a reminder when the post contains the word "thank" (a fancier algorithm should be invented, but you get the idea), so that noise could be eliminated at the first place.

I mean something like the golden box in the screenshot below.

> [image: screenshot of existing burninate-request reminder]

We can tell those who are going to thank other in the post:

> On Stack Exchange, there is really no need to thank others in your post. [Anything that is not relevant to the post is noise and should be removed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/5399734) If you feel someone has helped you, you can upvote and/or accept their post to express you thankfulness.

Comment: What happens to posts that contain the word legitimately?

Comment: It is more of a problem with the suggested edit feature, substantial edits are almost never accepted by the reviewers.  Having it done by the machine, well, let's just say that the SE devs trust humans more than their AI coding skills :)  Probably accurate.  And definitely cheaper.

Comment: @Oded It should be nothing more than a *kind remainder*. If OPs think that word is necessary to their posts, they should be able to simply dismiss it.

Comment: I removed the status-review tag because the work going into [the new Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377768/how-might-the-staging-ground-the-new-ask-wizard-work-on-the-stack-exchange-net) will address the core problem.

Comment: @Rosie It might be nice to have a status tag for cases like this (it might be [meta-tag:status-declined]), or to close the question as "Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete." or add anote to Tim's post as comments can't help to filter posts.

Comment: In terms of what guidance to link to, there's also this MSE post: [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're looking at an overhaul of the ask question UI; we expect to run some preliminary tests with the cheese all rearranged, and some new cheese put into the mix.

Right now, it's a single box. People that fill out forms see that and think "Oh, this is like writing a letter." But if we break that down into *several* boxes, each asking for specific types of information, it *might* also not evoke people's natural tendencies to use salutations and closings.

In other words, it's no longer an *essay* question, it's a series of questions asking you to provide very specific information. Imagine going to wherever you go to renew or obtain a driver's license. If the form you filled out to get that processed just said "Please tell us why you're here" - you might feel inclined to end it with *thanks!*, and probably won't provide all of the information that they need. If instead you needed to fill out four or five bubbles that accepted just the right number of numbers, well :)

Going to mark this as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) as a means to make sure we come back and visit this again to see if the behavior naturally changes. I suspect that it will.

And, well, fewer suggested edits to review would be a welcome secondary benefit :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that less noise by construction is preferable to de-noising later. Alas, I get the "edits are expensive" kind of a vibe from the question, as if every edit was something to be done with utmost respect for limited space on the 4 available tape drives on the mainframe, and the cost of the operators that have to man the datacenter and swap tapes every few minutes. Edits cost next to nothing and nobody should IMHO refrain from an edit no matter how trivial it is. Sometimes you spot a typo and there's nothing wrong with fixing just that.