# How am I supposed to get good votes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, close-reasons

When I'm asking a question, it's because I don't know the answer. But what shall I do if everything I ask because I don't know the answer gets downvoted? I never get upvotes on my questions, but what am I supposed to do when apparently everything I don't know does not deserve being considered a good question? Am I asking only bad questions all the time? Or are the few people who vote me toxic? Look at these examples:

[How to pause/stop a running code in Java (Eclipse) by pressing a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619318/how-to-pause-stop-a-running-code-in-java-eclipse-by-pressing-a-key#)

or:

[How to check for multiple keys at once using keyTyped(event e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73796040/how-to-check-for-multiple-keys-at-once-using-keytypedevent-e)

-> a lot of code and detailed explanation of what I want. 45 / 52 people saw it and no one even bothered voting it.

On the other side:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729446/how-can-i-place-items-in-jframe-not-next-to-each-other

-> 18 views, two downvotes. Plus, the close reason is that it's not detailed enough, I must

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

What's unclear about it, how are there two or more problems asked? I asked for help because of one single problem and the closer said it's not focused on only one problem.

I'm constantly losing reputation and sometimes I just don't understand why. Is it possible that people don't bother upvoting good questions I post, but the bad questions are getting downvoted? Why?

What's the meaning of all this? I really feel like everything I'm asking is stupid and this makes me sad because at some point I don't even understand why my questions get closed or downvoted.

Edit (27.10.22): This may sound rude, but when I'm asking a question, I do it because **I** need the answer, not because I think other people might need to know. I can see that the questions should not be stupid, but imagine everyone would hesitate to ask for help in real life because they would think others do not need the answer to their question.

Comment: One major problem with the first two questions is that they seem to have too much code. You're not supposed to post all your code, only the shortest code possible that reproduces your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And how about this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782514/java-text-replaceall-except-or
It's very short and it's clear what I want. Still closed and three downvotes.

Comment: You don’t get downvoted for not knowing the answer. It’s fine to not know something - but you will get downvoted if your question isn’t useful  for the community as a whole. When you are posting, you should always be thinking of how you can make your question as useful as possible to other people who may have the same issue.

Comment: And what if no one else has the same problem?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782514/java-text-replaceall-except-or why do you repeat the answer that someone else already posted (The other answer was posted about 7 minutes earlier to yours)? Answer's aren't meant to be used to thank people.

Comment: Didn't know that. It was the first time I answered my own question. I expected it to be pinned at the top of the answer section and the whole question to be closed as 'question solved' or something.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires observation. Let me highlight two to illustrate. Your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73810886/424903) is closed as a duplicate of three existing ones. That there should tell you a lot already, most notably that Stack Overflow has existing answers that you should be looking for. Now take a look at [the edit you did here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73782514/revisions) which was undone by someone else. That should tell you that you are using the site in a way that is not intended. Looking for information should be the next step.

Comment: @Zero btw, it's likely posting your questions on meta here will attract people to view them and increase the number of downvotes they get (or perhaps people might upvote them). This is the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: Asking good questions and giving good answers is hard work. Some people just have a knack for making it look easy.

Comment: @Zero "I expected it to be pinned at the top of the answer section and the whole question to be closed as 'question solved' or something." That's what [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answers is for.

Comment: @beaker no, you are just as wrong. Not even the pinning to the top is true anymore and accepting an answer was never a way to close a question or mark it as solved. Just read the link you posted yourself, not a hint of it.

Comment: "The primary purpose is to build a repository of questions and answers. By its very nature, of course, that is going to help people, and that is the rationale behind creating the site... but it is _not_ the rationale behind _using_ it.,," ([What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601))

Comment: @gnat Does that mean the site's purpose is to collect questions and answers to help several people who might come into this situation, but at the same time not to help people who have individual issues?

Comment: linked answer suggests something like that: 'If you make the primary purpose "helping people" (with the implicit "at all costs" that goes along with it), and let "build a repository" be the secondary purpose, the secondary purpose _is_ going to get forgotten and SO will devolve...'

Answer (score 15):

[How to pause/stop a running code in Java (Eclipse) by pressing a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73619318/how-to-pause-stop-a-running-code-in-java-eclipse-by-pressing-a-key)
It's very unclear here whether you want to stop the application with the  debugger (as hinted by the title, and you thus look for a specific Eclipse Keybinding) or if you want to pause your own application while it runs without debugger. In the second case, you can't completely pause a program indefinitely while still listening to keyboard input. You either just want to pause parts of your application (maybe playing the sound?) but other parts of your app still need to run (keyboard listener). Without knowing what you actually want to pause, it's impossible to answer.

[How to check for multiple keys at once using keyTyped(event e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73796040/how-to-check-for-multiple-keys-at-once-using-keytypedevent-e?_gl=1*1dnl9fe*_ga*MTI5MTQ0NjgzMS4xNjYzNTk4NDQ3*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2Mzg1MDExOS45LjEuMTY2Mzg1MTM1OC4wLjAuMA..)
Hasn't received any downvotes and looks ok. If you want to improve it, you could cut down the code example. Is every line in there really relevant (even the commented ones)? Can you simplify the ui while preserving the same problem?

[How can I place items in JFrame not next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729446/how-can-i-place-items-in-jframe-not-next-to-each-other?_gl=1*1x7gjbn*_ga*MTI5MTQ0NjgzMS4xNjYzNTk4NDQ3*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2Mzg1MDExOS45LjEuMTY2Mzg1MTM1OC4wLjAuMA..)
This one lacks the (minimal) code of your UI. Possible also a screenshot of how it looks at the moment. Then there seems to be an inconsistency between the question which asks about RadioButton and JLabel, but in the comments you talk about a ButtonGroup.

The title could also needs some work, it only states what you don't want, but not what you want.

The question could, for example, look like:

> How can items in a JFrame be placed below each other?
>
> I have the following UI:
> `[INSERT CODE, should be at most 10-20 lines]`
> , but currently the RadioButton and the Label are placed in the same line. How can I modify my UI such that the two controls are placed below each other?

[Java Text replaceAll() except ',' or '.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782514/java-text-replaceall-except-or?_gl=1*80jrhe*_ga*MTI5MTQ0NjgzMS4xNjYzNTk4NDQ3*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2Mzg1MDExOS45LjEuMTY2Mzg1MTM1OC4wLjAuMA..)
This is too unspecific about edge cases, as also stated in the comments. It seems that there are several constraints not stated in the question, like that several consecutive "." should be treated specifically.

Even after reading all answers and comments, I still couldn't tell what the result of "054934....43" would be? 54934.43? 54934? 43? nothing at all?
Same for "4.3a4.5". 4.3? 4.5? Nothing?

Comment: At least I have an understandable, not toxic-sounding explanation now. Thank you! I would have upvoted this answer if it weren't for my reputation that I cannot upvote answers.

Comment: @Zero What is toxic is calling people toxic.

Comment: @philipxy You may be right. In my definition it's toxic to give destructive or even offensive criticism. And downvotes are criticism I cannot understand because sadly, they cannot be explained and a simple thumbs down is not helpful for me to understand why someone doesn't like my question.

Comment: @Zero Your writing does not reflect an understanding of how the site works & jumps to (negative) (wrong) conclusions.

Comment: You're right indeed. I'm technically still new to Stackoverflow.com, as I'm not very experienced here. However, if you have negative experiences, you jump to negative conclusions. And my experience on Stackoverflow.com tells me that someone will always have a problem with what I'm writing.

Answer (score 11):

### Get to the point

Looking at only the first question:

> Can anyone please tell me how to pause and how to stop a running program in Java by pressing a certain key on the keyboard? When pausing, I also want it to resume when hitting a certain key (for example the same key). What I don't want is a function to pause it temporary until a certain amount of time has passed or a function in the code to pause or stop it automatically. It should only pause/stop when I'm telling the program to do so by pressing a certain key.
>
> If you need my code, it's something like this:
>
> [code]

Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. Ask the question you want to ask. Do not use conversational language - just ask. Rearrange in order to explain things as you go. If you have existing code, it will usually be better to show it *before* the question. Do, however, explain the context briefly (what the code is trying to do). Thus:

> I have this code to play a tune when the user clicks a button:
>
> [code]
>
> Now I want the program to stop when a specific key is pressed, and resume only when a specific key (perhaps the same key) is pressed. How can I implement this?

Notice how much shorter that is? The main thing that has been cut out is the "what I don't want" part - because *there is no reason to expect* that someone would give you those things, if you **directly ask for what you actually want**. (Well, they might show you code with a function that pauses or resumes, because *that is a component of the most natural way to solve the problem* - all you need to do is make it so that *pressing the key calls that function*.)

### If you show code, show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Make sure that the code can be copied and pasted as is. Make sure it does not contain syntax errors (unless your question is about fixing a syntax error). If you need to explain something in the middle of the code, **use valid comment syntax**. Do not try to mark up code with boldface, etc. - it doesn't work.

Avoid irrelevant details. The code doesn't have to be, and *usually should not be*, simply an except of your code; it should be something **self-contained** that **represents the problem**. Rather than explaining that you omitted complex code to get a value to pass to a function, just show passing the value. It doesn't matter if it's the value you have in your actual code. Just show passing *a* value *that will demonstrate the problem*. If the value is selected by a user interface, **pick something the user could select and hard-code it**. (Unless, of course, the question is about that part of the user interface.)

**Don't add more than necessary**. If the question is about one specific part of the UI, don't show the code that creates or maintains other parts of the UI. If the question is about what happens when you click a button, skip the code for making the button pretty. On the other hand, if the question is purely about the UI layout, skip the event handling code. If the original code uses multiple resources, but *the problem can be demonstrated* using only one, then show only one.

Thus:

```
import org.jfugue.pattern.Pattern;
import org.jfugue.player.Player;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class playSong extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Player player = new Player();
    Pattern pattern = new Pattern();
    pattern.add("C4i");
    pattern.setTempo(120);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    this.add(panel);
    JButton song = new JButton();
    panel.add(song);
    song.setSize(100, 100);
    song.addActionListener(e -> { player.play(pattern); });
}
```

I haven't used Java seriously in many years, so I may have gotten that wrong, but you get the idea.

### Make sure the problem is well defined, and makes sense to ask

Rather than binding a keypress, why not make it so that another *button* pauses and/or restarts the song? Do you really want to stop *the program*? **What actually does that mean?** (I assume it does not include, "stop listening for events", since otherwise there would be no way to interact and tell the program to resume.) What actually needs to pause - only the *playing of the song*? Every *observable* thing the program is doing (animations etc.)? Should other parts of the UI become inactive? What exactly is the rule?

Also: what is the actual difficulty? Do you know how to make the program respond to a key press and do something as a result of that event? Do you know how to stop the `Player`? If you stop the `Player`, do you know how to resume the music from the same place again? *If you put these things together, does it solve the problem? If not, why not?* If you're missing exactly one of these pieces of information, then **focus the question on the missing part**. If you know how to do all those things, but can't put it together, then we are doing to need a more detailed explanation of how you are trying to put the pieces together and what goes wrong when you try. But most likely at that point, you have a relatively simple problem (a typo or basic logical error) that doesn't make a question that can help others.

Comment: Concerning "Get to the point":
Does that mean I must avoid trying to be nice or polite, and just bluntly say what I want without anything like "Please" or "Thank you"?

Concerning my player program, the final program is a collection of several buttons and each button plays another song. And I want to pause or stop songs which are currently playing, and start songs while other songs are currently paused.

Comment: Write bluntly, yes. Pleasantries like "please" and "thank you" are [liable to be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) ([also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721), and [also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160)). That **does not at all prevent** being [nice or polite](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 9):

A good question is not just a question that is not bad. Rather, it is a question useful to other people.

Let's look at one of the questions you brought up:

> And how about this one? [Java Text replaceAll() except ',' or '.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782514/java-text-replaceall-except-or) It's very short and it's clear what I want. Still closed and three downvotes.

It is not clear to me at all what the general problem is here. The code shows how to match "everything except digits"; the task needs "everything except digits, *or `','` or `'.'`"*. Basically, it starts at "except X" and seeks "except Y".

- The solution is trivial *research*: Literally add what you want to add, extending `\\d` to `\\d,.`.
- The general *usefulness* is low: Unless someone has the *exact* same problem, the start and end situation are basically the same: "except X|Y".

You might be able to salvage the last point by changing the title and body to ask how to *extend* a known working negative group. However, there is a good chance this is a duplicate and it might still get flack for the first point.

An additional issue is that the approach is unsuitable for the underlying task: A double literal is not "digits and commas and dots". For example, neither of `1.2.3` or `1...23` is a double yet both of `1.23d` and `1.234e2` are. As a result, the question description does not add up:

- Solving the requirements does not satisfy the task.
- Solving the task does not satisfy the requirements.

Answerers have to guess which one they actually have to solve. In addition, people with a similar question *for either problem* have to inspect both the question and its answers to figure out *which problem* is addressed.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the following question, one that I was directly involved with:

> [How can I place items in JFrame not next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73729446/)

You state above:

> -> 18 views, two downvotes. Plus, the close reason is that it's not detailed enough, I must
> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.
> Look at the question. What's unclear about it, how are there two or more problems asked? I asked for help because of one single problem and the closer said it's not focused on only one problem.

Currently, the question's text is:

> For example, I have a JFrame with a size of (x, y). Then I have a JLabel with a size of (x-200, y-200). And then a JRadioButton with a width of 100. How can I make the program place the JRadioButton below the JLabel instead of to its right? I want the program to know there shouldn't be placed anything more in this line.

And you have deleted a secondary question that was previously included:

> Edit: Is there also a way to place items below each other? For example, three JRadioButtons below each other and then again three RadioButtons below each other, but the two groups are in the same line?

---

And so yes, you have made your question more focused, and in a more perfect world, it would no longer be closed for being "unfocused" but rather closed as a duplicate of:

- [JFrame position three buttons one below another in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252229/jframe-position-three-buttons-one-below-another-in-the-center)

Or perhaps a duplicate of:

- [How to align multiple elements below each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628964/how-to-align-multiple-elements-below-each-other)
- [How to add sequence of JLabels right below each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866309/how-to-add-sequence-of-jlabels-right-below-each-other)
- [FlowLayout add under previous components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709887/flowlayout-add-under-previous-components)
- [Adding some JPanels (one below another) in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031004/adding-some-jpanels-one-below-another-in-jpanel)

Or perhaps a duplicate of the hits to be found in this Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com java swing position component below another one](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+position+component+below+another+one)

So, as you may see, Java Swing component positioning is a question/problem that has been addressed countless times on this site, and while that doesn't mean that new questions on this topic aren't welcome, if you are going to ask a new question on this topic, it's always best show the concrete results of your research and attempts in your question itself and use this to make the question better.

Consider posting links to prior similar questions on this site (as shown in the Google search link above) explaining how their answers do not solve your unique situation. Also tell what tutorials you've reviewed, including quite likely the relatively the easy to find Swing [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and explain if possible how this information doesn't help you directly solve your problem.  Doing this would likely result in a much higher quality question than the one you've posted, one that would likely be quite helpful to future visitors.