# I got downvoted for a well-asked question, while ChatGPT gave me correct answer. Should I always ask ChatGPT first before asking on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, chatgpt

I asked a genuine technical question on Stack Overflow:

[How can I customize Bootstrap with Sass if I use it via CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027499/how-can-i-customize-bootstrap-with-sass-if-i-use-it-via-cdn)

Currently it stands at -2 votes, 24 hours after asking. I am puzzled as to why. Nobody cared to provide any constructive feedback. What's even more interesting: ChatGPT was able to answer it, and thoroughly.

Is there some expectation now that if question is simple enough for ChatGPT to answer, it shouldn't be asked on Stack Overflow, or it will be downvoted?

**Update 7/30/2023**
Given [announcement of OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/), looks like I was on point :)

Comment: If chatgpt can produce a correct answer to your question, it probably wasn't a question worth asking here anyway. It's more or less an advanced "let me google that for you"

Comment: I edited the question to ask it better - by making the writing clearer, more explicit and less [noisy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) - and upvoted it. Aside from that, **this** question doesn't seem "genuine" in the same way - it reads like a rant about ChatGPT, or asking us to account for the behaviour of other, unknown users.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you, I appreciate that! I'll learn from your edits to ask questions better next time. This meta question is also genuine. I am truly unsure what is the "minimum bar for asking question on SO" and how it relates to ChatGPT. I thought that _even if_ ChatGPT can answer, it is still worthwhile to do Q&A here to build up the knowledge graph. But seems like I was wrong?

Comment: Creating new content here that doesn't already exist *is* valuable. It's just, if chatgpt is able to produce the answer... the answer is one that already exists out there... and if it's anywhere it's very likely here too. A quick search does pull up quite a few references of importing externals with sass.

Comment: @KevinB in such case I would expect for my question to be "closed as duplicate" with a link to the Q&A I missed, not necessarily downvoted. Or at least somebody could comment telling me I didn't search for existing Q&As thoroughly enough and point me in the right direction.

Comment: The two actions aren't mutually exclusive, but i would expect that as well.

Comment: @KonradJamrozik, if you just wanna ask ChatGPT programming questions, then you don't have to report back to us when you do.  You are at liberty to ask questions to whomever or whatever you wish.  It's just that, if you're trying to compare ChatGPT to Stack Overflow, you're going to run into the very blunt reality that these things are incomparable, and I personally bristle at the thought of someone wanting to say, "oh but ChatGPT did this, why can't you??"  Just use ChatGPT and leave us alone, if it means that much to you  /rant

Comment: @Makoto I didn't even occur to me to ask ChatGPT, at first. Somebody recommended it to me after my SO question got downvoted. But then I thought - wait - should I always _start_ with ChatGPT? Per the "do your homework first" recommendation for well-asked questions. My impression was that Stack Overflow values building up knowledge graph via Q&A, shortening further similar searches for other people. But I guess, based on your answer, I should treat asking ChatGPT as part of "doing my homework".

Comment: *"should I always start with ChatGPT..."* -- you should start wherever the heck you want to start. Period.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels per the guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

"Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem"

I believe it implicitly meant "you should at least google it". I am asking if it now implicitly means "you should at least ask ChatGPT about it".

Comment: @KonradJamrozik: So you're asking whether what you interpret to be "implicit" requirements, should be updated? Sure, update your own interpretation as you see fit, but I'm saying that this site and this meta should focus more on *explicit* requirements and recommendations. Again, use the tools that you want to use.

Comment: @KonradJamrozik:  I mean, if you want to ask a five-year old that can only regurgitate what it's been taught without extra context or the ability to verify that it's correct in any way, then sure, call that "having done your research".  ***I*** wouldn't.  But you do you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the statement "reasonable amount of time researching" is vague. But I do believe there was a community consensus so far that if one could google and find the answer within 10 seconds, then probably such question isn't necessarily worth asking on Stack Overflow, and may start getting downvotes without explanation. But I did just that (and more), didn't get an answer, and my question still got downvoted without explanation. Hence perhaps the community consensus has shifted on what the are the required research tools and I am unaware of it.

Comment: Community consensus has no bearing on how users 827649876 and 8762346 use their votes.

Comment: Again, you do what you see fit. Myself, I take much of what ChatGPT has to give with a huge grain of salt since the output that I've seen from it, while very well-presented, is often wrong. Again, I see no reason to add anything of the sort mentioned here to the explicit instructions to users or to my own implicit requirements, but as many others and myself have mentioned, you do what you feel is best.

Comment: @KonradJamrozik you are asking wrong people... Meta visitors has "community consensus" of 20-40 hours of research prior to asking is a good starting point. You also will not see any pushback against "q-ban gives you 6 months to prepare your next question"... Use whatever tools you have - and if ChatGPT is one that finds/points you the answer (vs. Google, MDN, asking friends/co-workers/random people on the streets) while you doing research no one here will complain that you *did not need* to ask question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that isn't really the case. Although we usually appear unsympathetic to q-banned users complaining here, personally I think the system is quite poorly designed, and I've gotten support in the past for my criticisms. Generally the problem is that, among the q-banned users, the ones most likely to come to Meta to complain about it overlap a lot with the ones who feel most entitled to ask questions.

Comment: How do you think chatGPT managed to answer it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've not seen any pushback on duration due to some limit on how much time it is reasonable to research a question to plausibly ask a good one... Indeed q-ban has other problems like sudden bun due to extremely poorly researched question or similarly not being able to recover from a single awful post... but "I need to ask a question urgently" is not something I've seen any support for.  (Otherwise, 6 months limit is not outrageous for the site - if all users ask just a single question a year SO will have 20 million questions a year to answer... )

Comment: Man if ChatGPT can answer the question, take it. You'll waste time testing and disproving its answers when it's wrong, but if on the whole you come out ahead, take it as a win.

Comment: Ask ChatGPT first since it is free (for now) and better (for you). What's more, you will not get downvotes.

Answer (score 34):

ChatGPT is orthogonal to this conversation.

Questions asked on Stack Overflow are still subject to the (admittedly random but most of the times there *is* a purpose to) curation and ranking of the community.  Two community members saw your question and felt that it wasn't useful to the site at large, so they chose to downvote it.  (If I *had* to hazard a guess, it reads like something you could figure out with simple local experimentation.  But I can't read minds.)

If you want to ask your questions somewhere else, knock yourself out.  Stack Overflow still has standards, though.

Comment: The question is 'Is there some expectation now that if question is simple enough for ChatGPT to answer, it shouldn't be asked on Stack Overflow, or it will be downvoted?'. ChatGPT isn't 'orthogonal' to the question, the question is about ChatGPT. The answer is 'no', at least until ChatGPT can provide reliable answers. At that point I suspect the community *will* expect that posters ask an AI first as part of 'reasonable' research, just as currently we expect a poster to at least ask Google first. It's possible that LLMs will never reach the point of providing reliable answers, of course.

Comment: @RichN: ChatGPT is *very* orthogonal to this conversation.  It doesn't matter if you ask your friend who works at Google, your college buddy who you had that one programming class with that one time, or a rubber duck that you nicknamed "ChatGPT"  with a Stick-It Note.  Who you ask *first* doesn't matter.  It doesn't matter if you asked an AI first.  *No one cares who you asked first* when you ask your question on Stack Overflow so long as you've done *sufficient* research to your problem and can demonstrate that *here on Stack Overflow*.