# Introduce a new post-owner-only flag that combines "no longer needed" with a notification of the commenter of an update to the post

Tags: feature-request, notifications, comment-flags, deleted-comments, comment-replies

<sup>For the backstory, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424500/45375) about prematurely deleted, user-targeted "please see my update" comments.</sup>

**Motivation:**

- Prevent comment proliferation by making a dedicated flag available to post owners in the following scenarios:

  - In a comment, the post owner of a *question* has been asked for clarification / has been encouraged to include additional information.
  - In a comment, the post owner of an *answer* has been asked for clarification of aspects of the answer, typically by the asker.
- The new flag would allow the post owner - after having updated the question / answer - to combine the "no longer needed" (NLN) flag with *an automated behind-the-scenes notification of the commenter* (whose identity is implied by the comment being flagged) that their comment has been addressed in an update to the *post*, as fleshed out below.

  - To be clear: Not *all* comments warrant updating of the *post* in response, but it is common especially for questions, and often useful for answers, *assuming that the update is of general interest*: instead of responding in a *comment* - creating noise that may have to be cleaned up later - the post itself is improved.
  - The notification should be omitted if the commenter is already *following* the post in question.

**Benefits:**

- Ephemeral comments whose only information content is "please see my update" are prevented - no need for later cleanup.
- Commenters are notified of post updates that are likely important to them, which is especially important for new and inexperienced / casual users.

  - Yes, there is the option to 'Follow' a post, BUT:

    - *Update*: **tl;dr: No one should have to 'Follow' a post if all they care about is reliably getting notified of targeted replies**, [which overzealous flaggers can currently prevent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424500/45375).
    - It is an advanced feature inexperienced users are unlikely to be aware of.
    - Those who do know the feature must (a) remember to use it and (b) may choose *not* to use it, so as not to be inundated with potentially unwanted, numerous notifications such as *incidental* post edits.
- The notification is *combined with cleanup of the comment.*

**Suggested implementation:**

- Provide a **new flag** - available to the post owner only - labeled something like this:

  - "No longer needed. *Also notify the commenter that their comment has been addressed in an update to the post*."
- The flag would act as follows:

  - As with current "No longer needed" flags, a moderator would have to agree in order to get the comment removed.
  - *Irrespective* of whether removal is approved, and assuming the commenter doesn't already follow the post, *a notification is sent to the commenter* using a *canned message*, something like:

    - "You have posted a comment at `<clickable link>`, and the post owner has indicated that they have addressed the issue raised in you comment in an update to the post."

---

**To address feedback**:

- A recurring theme in the comments, re potential for abuse and unilateral notifications:

  - The proposed flag constitutes as much or as little potential for abuse as @-targeted reply comments *already do* - and to me such targeting is an invaluable part of the commenting system.
  - The new flag would simply streamlines the process and cut down on comment noise.
  - In other words: Via @-pinging, users already have the power to unilaterally notify others - this proposal doesn't introduce anything new. The discussion of whether unilateral notifications *in general* are worth having is an entirely separate debate.
- *If* there's concern about the proposed new form of unilateral notification occurring *behind the scenes*, the notification aspect too could be made contingent on moderator approval.

  - Personally, I don't see the need for that, especially given that user do not control the *content* of the proposed notifications.
  - Someone abusing it to *annoy* another users could easily be addressed by raising the issue with moderators. Also note that this can happen at most *once* for a given comment a user has made.
- Re making the flag available to others too, not just the post owner:

  - I am open to that; my initial thought was it would only be of interest to post owners, but users who edit someone else's post may want to use it too.

Comment: This would also help with updates that address multiple people's comments.  As you can only @mention one person per comment, askers often end up posting multiple "@person please see update" comments in this scenario.

Comment: Why is the decision to notify up to post owner? If a commenter wants to be informed about changes, they can *follow* the post. If they don't want to be informed, well, why encourage someone else to prod them?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the decision _is already up to the post owner_: They can always post an @-targeted comment - and this proposal would _eliminate that noise_, especially if the only content of the comment would be "see my update".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, also, the problems with the 'Follow' feature are already discussed in the proposal.

Comment: @mklement0 "discussed" is a strange term for only alleging ignorance and forgetfulness.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, they are arguments: engage with them or not - your choice. Don't post comments that pretend they haven't been made.

Comment: @mklement0 You've just shut down my arguments with a blanket "it's already been discussed". How should one engage with that? oO

Comment: What prevents the author of the question from abusing the flag and unnecessarily pinging other users?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I didn't shut anything down: I pointed out that instead of engaging with the arguments that were already part of the post with respect to the 'Follow' feature, you in essence said "but there's the 'Follow' feature". When I pointed out the non-engagement with the arguments, your idea of then engaging them appeared to be to call them "strange" - duly noted. But let's not get side-tracked: the issue is that users already have the power to send notifications, via @-mentions - this proposal would simply streamline the process and make it less noisy.

Comment: @SecurityHound, what prevents post authors from abusing @-targeted comments? See also the previous comment.

Comment: @mklement0 I called the assertion that the feature was discussed "strange". The actual arguments I would call patronising. They appear to deny the very agency of people to decide whether they want to be informed. In essence, I said "I have agency to decide when to follow and would like that to be respected".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I exercising my agency to opt out of this conversation, because to me it is a red herring: Via @-pinging, users already have the power to unilaterally notify others - this proposal doesn't introduce anything new. If you have a problem with unilateral notifications _in general_, this would  be an entirely separate debate that isn't worth having here.

Comment: @mklement0 An `@`-ping is something visible that gets seen and potentially acted on by the entire community. An invisible ping is an entirely different beast.

Comment: "*There is the option to 'Follow' a post, BUT: It is an advanced feature inexperienced users are unlikely to be aware of.*" The follow option is not advanced at all, and it's right there in front of users at the bottom of every post they read. Hovering over it or clicking on it tells you exactly what it does: notifies you of updates. I'm not convinced we need _this_ as an improvement here. Maybe the "Follow" feature should be changed to only follow edits to the post rather than all the other actions it follows, instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, as noted in my comment on your answer: if that is a concern (one that I don't share), the notification part could be made contingent on moderator approval too, not just the comment-removal part (as is already the case).

Comment: @TylerH, lots of things are right there - that doesn't mean that users pay attention to them or learn how to use them, especially if they're not _necessary_ for using the site. But the larger point is that (a) users shouldn't have to take _extra action_ to be notified of relevant updates directly targeted to them and (b) being notified on _every edit_ could still result in a flurry of unwanted notifications.

Comment: @mklement0 Not paying attention to site features does not make them advanced or esoteric. It makes users lazy. I don't particularly want to cater to lazy users. Not when there are far more important things SO devs could be working on.

Comment: @TylerH, I should never have engaged the 'Follow' debate: it is irrelevant. It is unrelated to receiving the _targeted notifications_ that this suggestion is about. No one should have to 'Follow' a post if all they care about is reliably getting notified of targeted replies, which [overzealous flaggers can currently prevent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424500/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 - They have abused it. I have been called absolutely horrible things in a comment. We don’t need additional ways to ping users.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't see the relevance of abusive comments like that to this proposal.  The users can _already_ ping people with abusive comments.  This is giving them a way to do it in which they _cannot_ insert abuse.

Comment: @SecurityHound: what Ryan M said. To be explicit: the proposal involves a _canned_ message whose content the flagger doesn't control.

Comment: IMHO, the largest issue with this proposal is that it's a mod flag. I imagine the mod reaction to this flag being "uh...maybe that's NLN now...? I don't really want to read through this and try to figure out if it was actually addressed, because that's really for the comment author to judge." If something like this were to be implemented, I'd probably structure it as a notification to the commenter that the issue has been addressed, and let them decide whether to remove the comment, reply further, or ignore it entirely.  And then we could safely consider all "please see edit" comments NLN.

Comment: @RyanM, as proposed, you, as a moderator, can treat this as just like any other NLN flag. Nothing else to figure out. If the commenter believes their comment has _not_ been addressed, they now _know_ what the situation is - and are free to post a _new_ comment. (Again, I don't think the _notification aspect_ needs mod approval).

Comment: You claim the "follow" function is too advanced/unknown, but then propose a more complex feature that relies on users that aren't even interested in moderation tools. That's not going to work at all. Do you remember the "thanks" reacts, that were supposed to reduce the "thanks" comments? They didn't work. It only added more noise.

Comment: @RyanM Out of interest, how many (ballpark figure would suffice) “I addressed your comment” comments are actually accompanied with flagging the addressed comment? Usually, I am the one cleaning up after seeing an update (provided the comments were actually addressed). This would suggest many post owners just ping, they don’t flag for removal in the first place. Am I just exposed only to a niche or is this usually the case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, so it sounds like this proposal will do what you're looking for - removal of the original comment and no pinging noise - and the problem may be just one or making users aware of the new flag. As for my personal MO: I _eventually_ flag the original comment for removal, but only after a shared understanding has been reached or I have inferred from the commenter's presence on the site that they've seen the ping and haven't responded (or have responded indirectly, by accepting the answer).

Comment: @gre_gor, while I do think that 'Follow' is an advanced function that inexperienced users are unlikely to use, I have since realized that discussing it is incidental to this suggestion, because you shouldn't have to follow a post just to receive a targeted notification. The proposed new flag would indeed primarily benefit experienced who know how to flag, probably more _answers_ than _askers_, given that many frequent contributors answer more questions than they ask. Experienced users are precisely the target audience. By contrast, I can see why the thank-you experiment failed.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see a point in this.

If I want to be informed about changes of a post, I follow it. If I don't want to be informed, then I don't follow it. It's really not a feature that is super advanced or hard or difficult to remember.
The button is readily visible and actually very close to the comment section.

That people feel the need to create additional pings via comments is unfortunate. But often enough, not just the comment is noise but the ping as well. Giving authors a reminder that they could ping everyone who commented seems at best neutral in terms of removing noise.

That said, in situation where a ping is appropriate, it's not clear to me why the author should be the only one to raise them. We have heaps of curators that comment, review, edit. An initial comment may just as well become obsolete due an edit or even a general, clarifying comment by anyone else.

Comment: Pings in comments are a valuable tool. As any tool, it can be abused. The premise of the suggestion pertains to _appropriate_ pings, as described. I'm personally open to letting others raise this flag too.

Comment: @mklement0 Limiting the discussion to *appropriate* pings seems to be begging the question. *Lot's* of things would be useful if only used appropriately. The big problem is that very often they aren't. Giving people the option to invisibly prod others while also nuking comments seems very open to be used not just appropriately.

Comment: Nothing would change with respect to nuking comments - moderators would have to agree. If abuse is really a concern, the notification part could be tied to moderator approval too.

Comment: As I said the last time the follow feature was raised as a solution to this: The "Follow" button produces an absolute _torrent_ of notifications when you want _one_.  As currently implemented, it's not a very good solution to this problem.

Comment: @RyanM I follow practically every single question or answer to which I add a significant comment or vote. I'm well aware of its shortcomings. That doesn't mean that this proposal is automatically better. That *one* notification I want usually isn't when the OP is totally convinced they addressed everything, unlike last time, or the time before.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the proposal isn't _automatically_ better, it is better _for the reasons stated_ (now updated to address the 'Follow' fallacy).

Comment: @RyanM can only speak for myself, but I've been following each and every post I make any action on (apart from a subset of flagging actions), even wrote a publicly available script for doing this automatically. Never had an issue with managing notifications (certainly not on main) - there was an inconvenience with notifications being marked as read all at once before the inbox change, but even that is a non-issue now. Even following meta posts doesn't result in an unmanageable stream of notifications.

Comment: @mklement0 I urge you to stop this "discussion" style of simply asserting your stated reasons are sufficient and brandishing disagreement as fallacies. Following isn’t a fallacy, I can attest it works well for me and apparently, judging by comments, for others too. I consider your dismissal of my person and agency like that as highly offensive. FWIW, this is exactly the kind of situation in which I don’t trust the author to decide for me that they have addressed my concerns.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Stating that something is a _particular, named_ fallacy _is_ an argument - a shorthand for a common logical error. If you disagree that it applies, _argue why it doesn't_. No one is disregarding people and their agency here; I haven't "dismissed"  your points, _I've argued against them_. Such perceptions are your choice, and I urge you to stop writing comments fueled by them.
The only productive forward that doesn't cause bad vibes is to either engage the arguments, or -  if you believe that you've made your points but aren't being heard - to stop commenting.

Comment: My (accidental) bad: I thought you were talking about the named fallacy I referenced in a comment on Karl's answer and the ones mentioned in [this previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424516/45375). In the case at hand, "'Follow' fallacy" was shorthand too: _for the arguments in the updated initial post, which my comment explicitly mentioned, arguing that and why the 'Follow' feature isn't relevant to this proposal_, which you're still free to engage with. Disagreement and arguments aren't dismissal - conflating them is a recipe for misery.

Comment: With my mistake regarding what I thought you were referring to  corrected, I am now taking my own advice (again):
I've made my points. I feel I have't been heard. I am opting out of this conversation.

Comment: @mklement0 Your points haven’t been heard because they are plastered over multiple Q&A and somehow you expect people (or at least me) to magically be able to piece all of that together. If you want to take another shot, please do so, but do so realistically. If you want to opt-out, then do so - don’t keep on talking while you say you stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253526/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-mklement0).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, people comment on an answer requesting clarification because there is something actually confusing (or incomplete, ambiguous, etc.) about the answer that really ought to be cleaned up for everyone's benefit. This is all well and good; answers exist for everyone's benefit, after all. The answerer can take this feedback into consideration, improve the answer, and mark the comment NLN. There is no good reason to notify the commenter, because the changes are not made for the commenter's benefit, but for everyone's. The commenter should not be motivated by self interest, because this is not a discussion forum.

Other times, people comment requesting clarification because of some idiosyncratic, personal concern - i.e., "how do I apply this advice in *my* particular situation?" In general, we don't teach or mentor here - this is not a discussion forum. However, if there is genuinely something interesting about the commenter's situation that makes the existing answer not apply - while *also* not substantially critiquing it as an answer to the OP - this indicates that the commenter really has a *new question* that should be asked separately, clearly distinguished from the current one, and *focused* on the aspect that isn't already addressed in this answer. Either way, these requests for clarification are not ordinarily useful. They should just be marked NLN. Responding to them encourages inappropriate use of the software as if it were a discussion forum, which it is not.

That said, generally it might be useful if new users received automated feedback from the system the first few times that their comments were removed as NLN, perhaps with a hyperlink to a help page about commenting policy.

Comment: FWIW: handling "No longer needed" flags on substantive comments is often...tricky.  It can be hard to tell _why_ the flagger thinks it's no longer needed, and if it's something related to technical merits, then we're trying to make a technical call in an area where we're not necessarily a subject-matter expert, often with no explanation from the flagger.

Comment: @RyanM one of the many conclusions I've drawn is that SO suffers greatly from trying to cover all programming topics under one roof. It'd be really nice if a SME were reliably on hand for moderation.

Comment: That said, the idiosyncratic ones are pretty easy to judge (pretty much always remove).  I would think those would just continue to be flagged as NLN, even if this or a similar feature were implemented.

Comment: [False dichotomy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424516/45375): "There is no good reason to notify the commenter, because the changes are not made for the commenter's benefit, but for everyone's"

Comment: @mklement0 no; the false dichotomy fallacy is when one's argument relies on falsely supposing that of two possibilities must necessarily be the case. I am not doing that here; I am, instead, asserting that one possibility is correct, and also denying that another possibility is correct. While there are other possible answers to the question "for whose benefit are these edits?", those are **also** incorrect. For example, it would be incorrect to say that the edits are for the benefit of everyone *except* the commenter - fortunately, I didn't say that.

Comment: Except you _are_ saying that: "not for the commenter's  benefit". If you had said "not _only_ for the commenter's benefit", it would be a different story.
But doing so would contradict what you're advocating for here, and [have advocated for before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424503/45375): 
either not notifying a commenter at all of an important update, or - by premature removal - depriving them of a notification explicitly targeted to them.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever other valid objections one may have to this (which I'm not addressing here), **I object to the idea that the "Follow" feature solves this problem.**  This proposal may or may not be the right solution for this problem, but the "Follow" feature, as it exists today, is not.

When I vote on a question and leave a comment describing the reason for that vote, **I want to be notified in one circumstance only**: someone (probably the asker) believes that the issue I described has been addressed.

I do not want to be notified if:

- Someone tweaked the tags on the question
- Someone has told the asker to read the Tour and How to Ask
- Someone else's comment has been addressed
- Someone posted an answer
- The question was closed (that was probably what I was trying to achieve with my vote<sup>1</sup>!)
- Someone edited something in the question unrelated to my comment, like fixing spelling/grammar
- Someone is having a long multi-comment back-and-forth in the comments with the asker trying to clarify the issues and get the question fixed.

All of these things generate notifications for followed questions!  The last one generates quite a few!  They are all pretty common occurrences!  It makes the inbox borderline unusable, and so **I basically never follow questions<sup>2</sup>, even though *I would generally like to revisit questions I've commented on if someone believes the issue is fixed*.**

---

<sup>1</sup>: Obviously not applicable to *me* on Stack Overflow, because I'm a moderator and can unilaterally close questions, but applies to the network in general and to everyone else who's not a moderator.
<sup>2</sup>: ...except for moderation purposes, where I do in fact often want to know if *anything* happens on a specific post.

Comment: I think most of that could be solved by a more fine grained "follow" feature. Relying on users to properly use "this edit addresses this comment" is not going to work. Just like a lot of closed posts are pushed into the reopen queue by useless edits from OP.

Comment: "someone (probably the asker) believes that the issue I described has been addressed" Judging by how often I have seen closed questions with the “close reason was addressed” bit set when it was totally inappropriate, I am having a hard time entrusting this to the asker. Yes, the follow feature isn’t ideal but that means we need realistic improvements that are feasible in practice.

Answer (score 3):

If I leave a comment on a question suggesting the user simplify their code snippet, or add a code snippet, or anything else, I don't need to know when they've done it, I've moved on, there's 20 million other questions. If there's an exception and I *do* want to be notified when things change with a given question, I can use the feature that was built for that purpose. If that feature is too noisy, or not working well... maybe *that* should be the feature request.

You've asked the equivalent of an X/Y question. You've identified that it's problematic when OP's (mis?)use the comment feature to notify past users that a problem has been resolved, when in reality the OP should be flagging those comments as no longer needed given the problems have been resolved. You're proposing a feature to normalize users abusing the comment feature to produce extraneous notifications that no one has asked for.

Answer (score -7):

### I agree with this.

I recently posted a question and two people asked for some details. So, after seeing both and edited my question, I had to add two comments, like "@ someone Ok thanks. I just updated my post", which make appear "Show x more comments" and literally spam.

I understand some people don't want to have notifications, but if they ask for clarifying, why they would not see it? There isn't any reason except "I don't like notifications". So, maybe it can be fine if there is an option to disable tag notification or something, but it's another feature request.

Finally, we could also imagine a button to be notified when the user edit the post, which could work the same as "Add to review" button when edit a closed question.

Comment: I mean... i don't like notifications because the new inbox is absolutely awful. If i want to be notified of a post being updated I'll subscribe to it. That's opt-in and non-intrusive. Yes, people can still @ me directly if they want, however that gives me an opportunity to give mods more work.

Comment: In defense of this: by posting a comment, you are opening yourself up to being pinged.  That is just how comments work on Stack Exchange!  People reflexively removing these follow-up pings via flags are _preventing_ the comment system from working as designed.

Comment: Also re: "an opportunity to give mods more work" - this proposal seems to reduce the number of NLN flags mods have to handle from 2 to 1 per comment requesting improvement (or fewer, if the person notified deletes the comment themself), as well as reducing the need to think about whether the comment still has value (i.e., notifying someone of an update they requested).

Comment: No such comments should even exist. Implementing a feature that requires such comments to function is counter-productive.

Comment: @KevinB, such comments (@-pinging users even with just an _abstract_ note pointing to a post update) not only do exist, they are currently of vital importance _until such time they've served their purpose_. This proposal eliminates all related headaches: (a) overzealous flaggers preventing the comments from serving their purpose via premature removal and (b) conversely, obsolete comments needlessly lingering.

Comment: It's worth noting that some moderators find these sorts of NLN flags unhelpful, and will decline them if the user hasn't been online since the reply comment was posted.  Unfortunately, due to regressions in the Stack Exchange platform making it more difficult for moderators to see the last-online time, this has become much harder.