# Where can I ask why my question in SO is bad and why I get downvotes?

Tags: discussion

Over some weeks, I have got many downvotes, and many closed questions, but I do not know why.
I read *How to ask a good question* and some article in meta about that, but I have not found the cause of this reaction by the community.

I'm trying to find a place to discuss and explain the problem with my questions, to learn, and I want justice about users' downvotes and closing of my questions.

I think the SO community needs somewhere for new users to ask questions and for answerers to calm down and get answers in detail as to why these questions are bad, and new users learn from it. All articles are not useful enough for many users.

Comment: What does "ITNOA" mean?

Comment: Because it's a tagline, @sorosh_sabz . You have/had it in plenty of your other posts. Taglines aren't allowed, please don't use them. Other curators, and even moderators have removed them from your posts too (I wouldn't be surprised if the mod messaged you to ask you to not use it when they did too, but I have no evidence to say they did).

Comment: @ThomA Did I understand correctly that you downvoted for tagline reason?

Comment: I didn't say anything about votes, @sorosh_sabz. Where do you see me talking about my vote here..? I haven't stated if I voted on this question, nor if it was an up or down vote.

Comment: @ThomA Ok so I do not understand correctly, I really want to know and want to learn about why down votes, thanks to get advice to me

Comment: It looks like your recent questions are getting several comments explaining the issues. It also doesn't look like they're attracting close votes, so it may just be that people don't find them interesting. (Although personally I think it is bad to have things on the site that are scored below 0; that should be reserved for things where there is some contention that they need to be closed and improved.)

Comment: You could start by explaining what ITNOA is, and why it's important to *every single one* of your posts. I've seen countless users ask you about it and you have never responded. What is ITNOA an acronym of, and how does it relate to downvotes, C#, and Docker (to name a few).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I do not understand, Did you say, that people down vote my question, because does not like (interest) my question?!

Comment: The reason is on the tooltip, @sorosh_sabz : the question does not show research effort; it is not useful or helpful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel as you can see in this question, many people get down votes without say any reason :(

Comment: And still no answer about ITNOA...

Comment: @ThomA I search many article about good question, and read Help Center (as you can see in this question, I say explicitly about `How to ask a good question and some article in meta about that`, How anybody can say does not show research effort?!

Comment: Please stop posting ITNOA, whatever it means. It's noise and the perseverance with which you do it is a valid reason for account suspension.

Comment: @Dharman yes, because the law is here, I do as you say

Comment: For reference: tags are [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) that we don't want in questions or answers because this is **not a discussion forum**. The site already credits you for your contributions automatically.

Comment: @ThomA for example why questioning about protobuf in C# does not useful or helpful?!

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - First, you are receiving feedback, on how to improve the quality of your questions. Second, there is a place to get more verbose feedback, Meta SO. Third, “I think the SO community needs somewhere for new users to ask questions”, sounds wonderful but who exactly will be answering these low quality questions that are already unacceptable at SO that they were closed until such time they were edited so they could be answered?

Comment: Considering you've ignored one of the most repeated questions in the comments, I'm out, @sorosh_sabz .

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76283026/how-to-get-c-sharp-interface-from-my-proto-services) low quality, question that doesn’t explain, where specifically in the process you are stuck or the code you need help with that reproduces the problem you face? Your question has been not well received for justified reasons.

Comment: @SecurityHound I overhaul [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76283026/1539100) question, but I do not know, is better or worse?

Comment: I’m getting more and more curious: what the heck is «ITNOA»? As you’re so stubborn not to tell us, is it fair of us to consider you trolling?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - Your question about C# does not contain a single line of code.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship as you can see in Dharman, I say does not repeat again in any question or answer in SO

Comment: Dharman did not ban you from telling us what it means.

Comment: @SecurityHound because it is about ability, and it is irrelevant to syntax, it is about specific library feature and some concept in C#, and does not related to specific code, to I write it in this question, Did you agree with me?

Comment: Your stubbornness not to answer our valid questions, is grounds to close this Meta question for «needs details or clarity». Your seemingly eager will to ignore feedback you’re given, is grounds for closing it for «not seeking input or feedback».

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship if you want to know meaning of ITNOA (when I say does not repeat again in SO), I can say it is my personal word from when I was student, to start my question in all sites, but I know, in SO, it is prohibited to say some hand-made word, so I do not repeat again. I hope this description answer your question, and does not close this question, from very not related cause.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - if Jon Skeet can’t even answer your question, it should be improved, so it can be answered by anyone with the necessary knowledge to do so.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz No, it doesn’t answer the question at all. It does however lead me to believe that you’ve been prefixing your questions with some word that has a sentimental or religious value to you. It doesn’t have any value to anybody else. When you post on SO, you’re supposed to post for others, not yourself.

Comment: I’m also not sure if you’re deliberately misunderstanding Dharman. He told you to stop putting «junk» into every post of yours, and that this is abuse of the platform, which will eventually lead to a suspension. You’re not censored or otherwise banned from telling us about it. Just stop incorrectly using the site. Also, Dharman is a moderator, not a dictator. By all means, he’s a very reasonable person, and what he said is correct, but don’t be afraid that he’ll abuse his powers against you.

Comment: "justice about users' downvotes and closing of my questions" You have no reason to think you aren't getting it. "answerers to calm down" You have no reason to think they are not calm. Commenters are writing about technical properties of your posts to help you & improve your posts; act on the feedback. You are jumping to negative & wrong conclusions. Like many many you just can't believe that your posts are bad so you believe people are mean. You are getting justice from calm people & you are shooting the messenger & your posts have problems.

Comment: As a side note, the thing about taglines isn't unique to [so]; it's a rule across the *entire* network. I note that you do that same thing on [other sites you have an account on](https://stackexchange.com/users/1673022/sorosh-sabz?tab=accounts), such as [su] and [SF]. Tag lines should not be used there either.

Comment: So OK, I finally understood more of less the meaning of "ITNOA" (Explanation [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424763/#comment958218_424763)), and I meant to post this Comment as a "Joke", but nope!!, I'm very impressed, but you "beat me"...!: "ITNOA+sorosh_sabz" = 3.9k Results > "FCI+chivracq" = 3.55k Results on 'Google', while I've been using the "[FCI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info)" Acronym in about 10 years full-time answering a Tech Forum (+ maybe 30 or 40 Answers on SO), but many more Comments asking for "FCI"... [Can't put the 'Google' Links, too short...]

Comment: At least the acronym FCI has a meaning and therefore a use, @chivracq . The OP appears to describe theirs as a "made up word", so it's not even an acronym for something. It literally has *no* meaning.

Comment: @ThomA, beh yep, I was also a bit "baffled", especially because I really had to look for the Explanation (lost in 17 (hidden) Comments), and several Users had to ask them (= the OP) before they finally gave some Explanation what it meant... Boah, why not... Now we can start using "ITNOA" in all our Posts/Comments/Answers on 'SO' and 'Meta' and 'Twitter' and 'FB', => #ITNOA is the "*new hype*" for 2023, ah-ah...! ("*I Truly Neglect Older Apes*"...? / "*Interactive Testable Neural Objects Axiom*" / "*Ingested Targets Never Oxygenate Again*"...!?)

Comment: Re *"ITNOA"*: This [isn't the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412280/are-windows-terminal-and-tmux-inherently-on-topic-for-stack-overflow#comment873264_412280)... (2021. Only visible to 10Kers and the OP.)  This supports the theory that absolute zero learning takes place by Stack Overflow users.

Comment: Related: *[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011)* (*"Religion or Other Beliefs .. If you're not answering a question specifically about religion on a religion-related Stack Exchange site, chances are it has no place in your content."*). And more generally: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)* and *** *** ***[Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/36828)*** *** ***.

Comment: Re *"my personal word"*: No, I think it is widely used (but for unknown reasons somewhat difficult to wrangle the meaning from the search engines; this is one example of where ChatGPT shines (a super search engine)—though it is also a pathological liar, so every response must be fact checked). I ***already had*** it in [my list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#in_the_name_of_Allah) (for many years), though it may have been due to the 2021 post. ITNOA = ***in the name of Allah***. —

Comment: cont' - A similar one is [ITNOJ](https://www.allaboutprayer.org/in-the-name-of-jesus-faq.htm): *in the name of Jesus*. Though [SIAs](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=self%20invented%20acronym) can not be completely ruled out.

Comment: @Thom A, *takendarkk*, *Dharman*, *Andreas detests censorship*: It was [resolved in 2021](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412280/are-windows-terminal-and-tmux-inherently-on-topic-for-stack-overflow#comment873264_412280): ITNOA = *in the name of Allah*. The reason for the obfuscation is unknown (perhaps an attempt to avoid having it removed?). BTW: [In one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18321067/revisions), it wasn't obfuscated (revision 1).

Comment: Related (gist: not different from other kinds of salutations): *[What to do about religious salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/what-to-do-about-religious-salutations)*

Comment: A similar salutation is [As-salamu alaykum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alaykum) ([many variations](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#As-salamu_alaykum) exist)

Answer (score 16):

First: as someone who has asked several dozen questions on the main site already and has had the account for more than 10 years, I would expect you to have better intuition by now about what appropriate questions look like. Of course, that has changed somewhat over the years, but not really that much. (My informal impression is that most of the important changes happened around 2014.)

For meta issues (which includes "what's wrong with this question?"), right here on meta.stackoverflow.com is the correct place to ask.

However, part of the point of Stack Exchange is that everyone is expected to be able to apply standard FAQ-type information to their own situation (since these sites **do not provide a discussion forum**); if there is still a specific concern, then questions should be asked in a way *that takes that into account*. Flooding Meta with "why is this question bad?" for several questions that were all obviously bad in the same way, is not going to go over well.

If a question was closed with a specific reason, and you don't understand why that reason applies, feel free to ask about it here. Make sure you can present a coherent argument as to why you think the reason *doesn't* apply. If you're wrong, we'll explain why. If you're right, we'll work to reopen (and possibly improve) the question (unless it should be closed for a different reason; usually we don't care very much if the closure reason is wrong).

> Why down vote? where I can ask this question?!

Downvotes on Meta work differently from the main site, and you do not lose reputation for them. A downvote on a question here does not necessarily mean that the question is off topic or problematic; it may mean that it is asking about something people consider obvious or not worth answering, or that it is proposing a change that people are opposed to.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you say, I ask question in meta only about cause of closed question, and I cannot question about many down voted question, So, where I can learn to why my question gets very down votes?

Comment: And as you say in last paragraph, I do not understand why this question is `obvious` or `not worth` for more than 8 users? where does this `obvious` come from? I think many people does not know why are their question bad? so how can this question is `not worth answering`?!

Comment: To be totally honest, it comes across to me that you have a habit of ignoring what you are told and re-asking your questions. Perhaps because you do not like what you are hearing?

Comment: If I do, I am doing very bad job and I feel really sorry for myself. But I really don't intend to do this, the reason why I insist so much here is because my work has been in trouble. and I hardly try to understand deeply your sentences meaning. but I think does not understand correctly, and asking in detail for better understanding

Comment: Ah. Perhaps the issue is English proficiency, then.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz: Re *"my work has been in trouble"*: [The bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is a possibility

Comment: @sorosh_sabz: A transactional approach, like [crossposting to several sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829506/console-cancelkeypress-does-not-work-properly#comment134533383_75829506), can be seen as exploitation of goodwilled unpaid volunteers.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz - If you require SO to perform your job, you need to figure out a solution to that problem, other than using SO has a critical resource to perform your job. Answers to your questions are not guaranteed, even if, they are high quality within scope questions