# Where to ask a question about SVN branching strategies?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about SVN branching and merging strategies, but I am not sure Stack Overflow would be the most appropriate place since the question is not strictly about programming.

If not here, where might I ask such a question in the Stack Exchange network?

EDIT: the question would be quite more focused than whether use branches or not, and it would rather be about how to solve a specific problem which is created from our current strategy (which I hardly can change).

Comment: Maybe [softwareengineering.se]? Although you're better asking there if it's OK there rather than here where it might be OK.

Comment: [To branch or not to branch?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/108298/31260)

Comment: @gnat [Bulletpoints everwhere!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307481/bulletpoints-everywhere)

Comment: @gnat thanks for the suggestion, but my question would be quite more focused then whether use branches or not, but rather how to solve a specific problem which is created from our current strategy (which I hardly can change)

Comment: @MatteoTassinari that would probably only make it better fit over there (that question I referred feels somewhat [too broad](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) to be a really good example). OTOH, very specific questions of that kind could be a better fit at SO than over there, see [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: @gnat after reading this (http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) I think I'll try ask over at Software Engineering

Comment: Meta suggestion for your meta post - just use [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) as branching there is essentially free :)