# Unexplained clutter in a post edited back in by author

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52825597/revisions

The author starts every post with a few symbols that do not seem to mean anything. Rather than explaining it, they edit it back in after the community approved my edits to declutter the posts. On the Security Stack Exchange site, the author does the same thing and [did not respond to a moderator asking why, back in 2015](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107532/when-can-i-commit-an-openssl-certificate-pem-to-source-control/107534#comment189769_107534).

It seems counter-productive to start an edit war. I'm personally okay with just dropping it, but that seems like it's counter-productive for the quality of the site (though, of course, in this case it is only marginally).

What should we do?

Comment: @RobertLongson [The previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687797), [The one before that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53419613), [and the one before that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399967).  Seems like a pattern to me.

Comment: And a look at [their commenting history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2146138/nathan-basanese?tab=activity) seems to bear out that premise.

Comment: Ahh, I was only looking at questions.

Comment: I mean, it totally makes sense for **comments**, although `#` would be more appropriate given the user's top tag.

Comment: It's an elaborate, 4-year long ruse to annoy the ___ out of everybody.

Comment: Down voting is valid but a custom moderator flag is what you should generally use for odd user behavior like this.

Comment: Remarkably, the author responded to the mod on Security.SE just now. Unfortunately they just said they can't comment on why they do it... Oh and they still used the '//' in the reply to the mod.

Comment: I'm getting popcorn for tomorrow - my guess there will be meta post about all those #*#* moderators that can't live just two slashes in each post alone... Should be mildly entertaining.

Comment: Judging from his overall writing style, sounds like one of those people who write differently for difference's sake. Cue neverending discussion on where the line should be drawn between respecting an author's personal writing style, and respecting community standards.

Comment: @CrisLuengo after looking at his posts, I think your 4-year long ruse theory is correct.

Comment: mm... Is this a low tech way to find his posts by searching? Does he have some kind of emacs addon where he copy/pastes SO posts directly into his C/Javascript code and hits [Ctrl+Meta+Greek+Hyper+SO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard) to paste content directly from his code editor to SO?

Comment: @jrh Would that be easier than just going to your profile? I could maybe see how that would help with comments but posts?

Comment: // , what the hell

Comment: I'd say it was some kind of hook character sequence for a bot but SEDE is so effective that I can't really see it being that useful, unless maybe he wants to access the site faster than SEDE allows? Maybe the bot aggregates everything he ever did on Github, LinkedIn, etc and compiles it into one giant resume on demand or something? But then again I can't see an employer being interested in comments like `// , Or security.stackexchange.com` and it seems like a very high noise way to make reference material

Comment: Related: I reported a (high rep) user for writing entirely in lower case, and then rolling back to insist upon it over several posts. Sadly a moderator decided it wan't worth the friction, so that user is now empowered, and more likely, to write in a wilfully irritating style. My only guess to explain this behaviour is the same as @BoltClock - a sort of strange defiance of community norms under the guise of uniqueness of personality.

Comment: The searchable posts premise is interesting, but trying to search "// ," on three different search engine curiously returns nothing, including SE itself. Maybe just my end though.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It falls under the [same heading as greetings, saying thanks, and signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). There is no place for it in answer posts.

I’ve removed the noise and reached out to the user.

Comment: Be interesting to know why he uses code comments to begin posts and comments.

Comment: @JonH I believe that the author is simply an [anticonformist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anticonformity). See BoltClock's comment: "_sounds like one of those people who write differently for difference's sake._"

Comment: @Cœur: I'm not going to comment on other sites.

Comment: As for motivations, we can only speculate. They use the exact same prefix on Github and LinkedIn, and either they have a specific purpose for it (to stand out, visually or detectable with code, so they can spot their own contributions on a page, perhaps) or are using it like others might use distinctive fashion choices. Unfortunately, on a platform that strives to create an encyclopedia of questions and answers, such 'personal touches' are actually distractions, which is why we would remove them *here*.

Comment: At least this is a minor formatting thing, unlike some [past examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307481/bulletpoints-everywhere/307545) :)

Comment: He is still doing it. Usually, Do moderators take actions for those types of things?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson on further investigation: they have not still been doing it. It’s fine in comments, if weird, but they haven’t added any new questions or answers with their “signature”. So no need to flag for that here.

Answer (score 11):

Nathan Basanese has already answered why he uses '//' in every post, answer, and comment:

> Would you believe me if I said it was a long-standing bet, resulting
>   from an argument about source control with a supervisor? Might not be
>   wise to *comment* on it regardless, because it would appear on meta that
>   I'm quite the rapscallion.
>
> Nathan Basanese - [Source](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/which-open-source-security-tools-are-considered-off-topic?cb=1#comment7982_3137)

Comment: That doesn't actually explain anything. What kinda bet is that, "if I win, you will prepend '// , ' to every post you write on the internet"? Anyway, thanks for referencing this, at least the author is not completely ignoring anyone asking.

Comment: This guy's alright in my book, because he used the word "rapscallion".